# Set default language using i18next + LanguageDetector

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using i18next for the first time in the project. My app has two languages: swedish(sv) and english(en). What I don't understand is that it for some reason sets `en` to the default language. For example when a user visits the site for the first time. This is my code:

```js
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
const options = {
  order: ['cookie', 'localStorage', 'sessionStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag', 'path', 'subdomain'],
  lookupLocalStorage: 'lng'
}

i18next.use(LanguageDetector).use(initReactI18next).init({
  interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
  detection: options,
  fallbackLng: 'sv',
  supportedLngs: ['sv', 'en'],
  resources: {
      en: {
          common: common_en
      },
      sv: {
          common: common_sv
      },
  },
});
```

As I set `fallbackLng: 'sv'`, the default language should be Swedish, but it's not? When a user visits the site for the first time, i18n sets `lng` to `en` in localstorage. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use this trick in your index.js

```
if (localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng') === null) {
  localStorage.setItem('i18nextLng', 'sv')
}

i18next.use(LanguageDetector)...
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

> [...] the default language should be Swedish [...]

No, because in your configuration you're taking the `navigator` into account. If the browser is configured to prefer English, your site will default to English (as it should).

Comment: My desired functionality is that the default language for any new user is Swedish. But if a user changes to any other language and refresh the page, the new language should be used. Do I even need `i18next-browser-languagedetector` for that?

Comment: No you don't. But defaulting to the user's preferred language as configured in their browser is generally accepted to offer the best user experience.